# mvc4 ef5 return points to folder not controller

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 sequential date fields: Start, End, Certify. When the user indicates he wants to update a date in a given row, I actionlink to the controller for that table, Task, where I have added code to determine which field is null and then direct to a view customized to that field. My concept was that the return would go to the scaffold generated edit where the data would be saved. So 3 views with a common return.

I'm getting a 404 error. Since I know the name is present, it must be unavailable.

The scaffold generated post code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Task task)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
 db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And my selection code:

```
public ActionResult EditBegin(int? id)
{
Task ViewModel = db.Tasks.Find(id);
{
if (ViewModel.SStart == null)
{
ViewModel.TaskID = id.Value;
ViewModel.SStart = DateTime.Now;
return View("EditStart", ViewModel);
}
else if (ViewModel.SEnd == null)
{
ViewModel.TaskID = id.Value;
ViewModel.SEnd = DateTime.Now;
return View("EditEnd", ViewModel);
}
else if (ViewModel.SCert == null)
{
ViewModel.TaskID = id.Value;
ViewModel.SCert = DateTime.Now;
return View("EditCert", ViewModel);
}
return View("EditCert", ViewModel);   //solves not all paths have return error
}
}
```

And in the  EditEnd view the EditorFor and Actionlink.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SEnd) // preloaded with NOW
@Html.ActionLink("Save End Date", "Edit", "Task" )  //is the TaskID passed back as part of this?
```

So in the EditEnd view, press the "Save end date" button and I get the 404 error. I've tested the Task edit function to confirm "the resource is available" and it works fine.

I've discovered the path is to a folder .../task/edit not the controller.

How do I get it to reference the controller. Removing the quotes doesn't help.

Thanks

My entire view is:

```
@model MVCBSV.Models.Task


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Scanedit";
}

<h2>Add Start Date</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Task", FormMethod.Post); 
<fieldset>
<legend>Task</legend>

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TaskID)

<div class="editor-label">
 Step Name
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StepName);
</div>


<div class="editor-label">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SStart)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.SStart)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
</div>

@*          <p>
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>*@
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Save Start Date", "Edit", "Task" )
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You edit method is decorated as an HTTP Post method. An anchor tag will provide a link which your browser uses to make an HTTP GET request. You can change from attribute to HttpGet and this will work.

However, it's better practice to actually POST a form to your save method.

Comment: I think I understand but no idea how to code this. I tried to "actually POST to a form" by adding Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Task", FormMethod.Post) to my view but no help.@MailmanOdd

Comment: Can you edit your original question to add the entire view? I'll see what I can do for you.